# F# A value or constructor is not defined, even though using get and set

Tags: oop, f#

I'm a first year CS student, with nor prior programming knowledge. We have just finished our time with functional programming, and have now gone to object-oriented programming. I'm currently working on an assignment, in which I have to imitate a race between animals. These animals have been given some attributes and methods, which defines their weight, maximum speed etc. One of the requirements of the code is that it has to generate a random variable, which determines its weight, for each instance it is called. So far I have come to this point in my code:

```
let rnd = System.Random()

type Animal (name:string, animalWeight:float, maxSpeed:float) = class

  let mutable foodInTakePercentage = float(rnd.Next(0,101))

  member val animalMaxSpeed : float = maxSpeed with get, set
  member val animalWeight = animalWeight with get, set
  member val neccesaryFoodIntake = 0.0 with get, set
  member val Name = name
  new (name, maxSpeed) =
    let minWeight = 70.0
    let maxWeight = 300.0
    let Weight = minWeight + rnd.NextDouble() * (maxWeight-minWeight)
    Animal (name, Weight, maxSpeed)
  member this.FoodInTakePercentage = foodInTakePercentage/100.0
  member this.CurrentSpeed =
    this.FoodInTakePercentage*maxSpeed
  abstract FoodIntake : float 
  default this.FoodIntake = 0.5 
  member this.NeccesaryFoodIntake = 
    neccesaryFoodIntake <- animalWeight * FoodIntake

end

type Carnivore (name:string, animalWeight:float, maxSpeed:float) = class
  inherit Animal (name, animalWeight, maxSpeed)
  override this.FoodIntake = 0.08
end

type Herbivore (name:string, animalWeight:float, maxSpeed:float) = class
  inherit Animal (name, animalWeight, maxSpeed)
  override this.FoodIntake = 0.4
end
```

The problem is that when this is compiled, I recieve the error message:

```
10g.fsx(22,5): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'neccesaryFoodIntake' is not defined
```

I have tried everything (of my very limited knowledge) in order to try to define it as a variable, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`necessaryFoodIntake` is a class member, not a free-standing value. To reference class members, you need to specify an object of that class, e.g. `x.necessaryFoodIntake`.

In your code, it feels like you're trying to reference the member on the "*current*" object, which is denoted `this`, so that's what you need to specify as the object:

```
member this.NeccesaryFoodIntake = 
    this.neccesaryFoodIntake <- animalWeight * FoodIntake
```

That said, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve with the `NecessaryFoodIntake` member. The way you defined it, it's a property with a getter, and that getter actually modifies another member (`necessaryFoodIntake`) and doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `unit`). Usually property getters are supposed to return a value and not modify state.

If you indeed wanted to define a member that modifies some internal state and doesn't return anything, you should (1) make it a method, not property, and (2) name it something more appropriate, e.g.

```
member this.CalculateNeccesaryFoodIntake() = 
    this.neccesaryFoodIntake <- animalWeight * FoodIntake
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to define a property with a single getter that returns the value of another member, you should not have it modify anything:

```
member this.NeccesaryFoodIntake = this.neccesaryFoodIntake
```

But that would be kinda useless, because now you have two members which are almost identical, except one of them is read-only. If you wanted to make `necessaryFoodIntake` inaccessible from the outside and then provide `NecessaryFoodIntake` as a public interface for it, you should have made the former `private`:

```
member val private neccesaryFoodIntake = 0.0 with get, set
```

In summary, while I can help you with your specific syntax error, the rest of the code seems off as well.

Comment: Yes it is unclear what NeccesaryFoodIntake does, since I forgot to upload the whole code. But ultimately its a variable that I want to change, depending of which type of animal it is (carnivore or herbivore) If I upload the whole code, it will maybe clarify my intentions:

Comment: Yes it is unclear what NeccesaryFoodIntake does, since I forgot to upload the whole code. But ultimately its a variable that I want to change, depending of which type of animal it is (carnivore or herbivore) If I upload more of the code, it can maybe clarify things: 
type Carnivore (name:string, animalWeight:float, maxSpeed:float) = class
  inherit Animal (name, animalWeight, maxSpeed)
  override this.FoodIntake = 0.08
end

type Herbivore (name:string, animalWeight:float, maxSpeed:float) = class
  inherit Animal (name, animalWeight, maxSpeed)
  override this.FoodIntake = 0.4
end

Comment: These don't actually touch `NecessaryFoodIntake` in any way.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin "In summary, while I can help you with your specific syntax error, the rest of the code seems off as well." If the OP fixes the syntax error, we would be happy to help them on [CodeReview.SE]. :)

Comment: I have recieved help from a student from the university. It has now been fixed. I would like to upload the code, but it seems to be too long, to upload here for some reason. Is there any way, for me to upload it ?